# how to proof for overlapping Dates within groups in oracle sql

Tags: oracle, group-by, overlapping-matches

I'm using oracle SQL Developer 21.4.3 to try to select records within groups without overlapping dates, however I haven't found a way to do this. This is an example of the table, we have to sets of dates, the technical date when the Record was created in the Table(DATE_FROM and DATE_TO) and the Expiration Date for the Product (VALID_FROM, VALID_TO)

Example (have)

| KEY | TYPE | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A | 10/31/22 | 12/31/99 | 12/31/11 | 02/28/25 |
| 123456 | B | 30/09/22 | 12/31/99 | 10/31/22 | 02/28/25 |
| 123456 | C | 10/31/22 | 12/31/99 | 02/28/25 | 08/31/35 |

Here the expiration Date for TYPE A and B are overlapping, at the end I only want to keep the Records with TYPE A and C, since these build a continous range using VALID_FROM and VALID_TO.

Example (want)

| KEY | TYPE | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | A | 10/31/22 | 12/31/99 | 12/31/11 | 02/28/25 |
| 123456 | C | 10/31/22 | 12/31/99 | 02/28/25 | 08/31/35 |

I have tried using the function ROW_NUMBER by ( PARTITION and ORDER BY) to identify the correct records but so far has not worked

Thanks for your help

Comment: Assuming that your date format is `MM/DD/YY` then type `B` has an invalid `DATE_FROM`.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a client application used to talk to a database; it is **NOT** a database and the version of the client application is irrelevant to the problem (and generally, which client application you use is also irrelevant to the problem). What you need to tell us is what the version is of the Oracle database that you are connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching and find the first row of each match (using `{- -}` to not output successive rows following an overlap):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
  ORDER BY valid_from, valid_to DESC
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN ( overlapping {- overlapping* not_overlapping -} | not_overlapping )
  DEFINE
    overlapping AS MAX(valid_to) > NEXT(valid_from)
)
```

Which, for the sample data (fixing the type `B` `DATE_FROM` value):

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (KEY, TYPE, DATE_FROM, DATE_TO, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO) AS
SELECT 123456, 'A', DATE '2022-10-31', DATE '2099-12-31', DATE '2011-12-31', DATE '2025-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, 'B', DATE '2022-03-09', DATE '2099-12-31', DATE '2022-10-31', DATE '2025-02-28' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 123456, 'C', DATE '2022-10-31', DATE '2099-12-31', DATE '2025-02-28', DATE '2035-08-31' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALID_FROM | VALID_TO | KEY | TYPE | DATE_FROM | DATE_TO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011-12-31 00:00:00 | 2025-02-28 00:00:00 | 123456 | A | 2022-10-31 00:00:00 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00 |
| 2025-02-28 00:00:00 | 2035-08-31 00:00:00 | 123456 | C | 2022-10-31 00:00:00 | 2099-12-31 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h09EzgjY)